# run parts of an vbscript as an administrator

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Hey i want to run this part:

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.run "powershell -command '& {Start-Service AxInstSV}'"
```

of an vbscript as an administrator. How can i manage this? My Computer is in an domain. Is it possible to run the powershell + the command as an admin from the vbs?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994

Comment: is set up it like this: `Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.run runas /user:username@domain "powershell -command {Start-Service AxInstSV}"` But it doesn't work!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use VBScript to call PowerShell?  Confused.  Why not start the service in VBScript, or just use Powershell on its own?

As for programatically running something with "run as admin", in order to use the "unrestricted token", I haven't yet found a solution other than configuring auto-admin-approval via Group Policy.

Comment: i have already fixed it was a problem with an windows account not with the code.